# (node:1788) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following warning (check commented line in the code), and I don't know how to add the promise() object as my function is not asynchronous.

```js
function MostProfitable() {
  var max = 0;
  var id;
  for (var i = 0; i < minmaxcoins.length; i++) {
    if (Number(minmaxcoins[i][4]) > Number(max)) {
      max = minmaxcoins[i][4];
      id = i;
    }
  }

  try {
    if (minmaxcoins[id][4] >= 0.6) { // error at this line
      console.info('Max coin: ', minmaxcoins[id][0], ' ', minmaxcoins[id][1]);
      console.info('Min coin: ', minmaxcoins[id][2], ' ', minmaxcoins[id][3]);
      console.info('Profit: ', minmaxcoins[id][4], '%');
      const d = new Date();
      opportunity = opportunity + 1;
      console.info(
        opportunity,
        ' ***********************************************',
        d
      );
      begin();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    begin();
  }
}
```

here's the error/ warning :

```
(node:1788) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined
    at MostProfitable (/home/root1/hft.js:274:20)
    at getMax (/home/root1/hft.js:261:2)
    at pairprice (/home/root1/hft.js:175:2)
    at getcoins (/home/root1/hft.js:116:1)
    at binance.bookTickers (/home/root1/hft.js:69:2)
    at Request.request [as _callback] (/home/root1/node_modules/node-binance-api/node-binance-api.js:3296:24)
    at Request.self.callback (/home/root1/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/home/root1/node_modules/request/request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
(node:1788) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1788) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I know it's just a warning but I notice that the app bugs as it's should work 24/7 non-stop. Can someone explain this problem?

Comment: Can you please show us `minmaxcoins` array ?

Comment: @Darshana Pathum thanks for your interest, minmaxcoin is just a simple 2D array created as follow: function createMatrix1(N, M) {
     minmaxcoins = new Array(N); 

    for (var i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        minmaxcoins[i] = new Array(M);
    }
    return minmaxcoins;
}

Comment: Is it possible that all numbers be negative?

Comment: @Saeed
 what do you mean?

Comment: If all `minmaxcoins[i][4]` be negative, the **id** stays undefined and the error appears. set the `var id=0` for example. there is some problem with your array!

Comment: i'll try to set if id !== 'undefined' and come back to you.. i guess that line is executed before the loop finishes which make id undefined

Comment: @Saeed still getting the same error

Comment: Add A sample of `minmaxcoins` in the question. @ALAEDDIN

Comment: @Saeed  I forgot to add typeof, so i secured the code with an if (typeof id !== 'undefined') {}  i guess it' should work this time without any errors.. i'll come back later if it works.

Comment: @Saeed It's works! please write an answer so i can give you credit

Comment: You solved it by yourself. Good luck. @ALAEDDIN